# How to optimise a sum of products for a combination of multiple variables over a time series period using GEKKO?

Tags: python, optimization, time-series, gekko

I'm trying to implement the optimisation of a cost equation in a 24h timeframe, meaning that I want to know the optimal combination of four variables (`p_sell`, `p_dg`, `pwr_grid`, `pwr_dr`) for each of the 24 one hour time instant. I have values for the other known variables (`p_grid`, `pwr_cl`, `pwr_fl`, `pwr_dg`) saved in arrays in the code below for simplicity. It seems simple enough, since it's just a sum of products with linear constraints, but I just can't seem to get it work.

[image: Link to image of the equations to optimise]

I tried to code this using GEKKO in python after reviewing many questions here but I couldn't seem to find an example implementation that combines optimisation of multiple variable (optimised together as a combination) and time series.

Below is my code, which is surely wrong, because it yields an equation definition error, reported below.

```
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

# data for 10th of January
pwr_cl = np.ones(24) * 584  # base load
pwr_fl = [185, 188, 167, 155, 168, 169, 168, 187, 190, 181, 211, 227,
          233, 230, 222, 216, 234, 237, 248, 250, 255, 247, 248, 206]  # variable loads in kW
pwr_dg = [1479.652, 586.589, 1452.378, 1452.822, 1249.333, 1112.853,
          1319.44, 1568.773, 1778.94, 1832.277, 1917.526, 1995.028,
          1955.759, 1900.253, 1781.595, 1548.431, 1495.562, 1496.265,
          1497.333, 1497.333, 1495.562, 1495.041, 1496.586, 1481.391] # renewables production in kW

c_sub = 10  # €/KW
p_grid = [0.1039, 0.09324, 0.08758, 0.07987, 0.09473, 0.1086,
          0.17634, 0.1849, 0.22304, 0.21307, 0.17866, 0.17144,
          0.16287, 0.16202, 0.16835, 0.18127, 0.19067, 0.20084,
          0.19173, 0.18842, 0.1822, 0.17953, 0.17208, 0.143]  # electricity cost from the grid €/kW

m = GEKKO()

# variables I want to optimise
p_sell = m.Array(m.Var, 24, lb=0.2, ub=0.3)  # electricity sale price
p_dg = m.Array(m.Var, 24, lb=0.15, ub=0.25)  # electricity purchase price from renewable sources
pwr_grid = m.Array(m.Var, 24, lb=0, ub=5000)  # power from the grid
pwr_dr_forecast = m.Array(m.Var, 24, lb=-750, ub=750)  # power that can be regulated by batteries

for t in range(24):
    pwr_grid_val = pwr_cl[t] + pwr_fl[t] - pwr_dg[t]
    m.Equation(m.sum(pwr_grid + pwr_dr_forecast) == pwr_grid_val)
    m.Minimize(p_grid[t] * pwr_grid + pwr_dg[t] * p_dg + c_sub * m.abs(pwr_dr_forecast)
               - m.max2(pwr_fl[t] - pwr_dr_forecast, 0) * p_sell
               - m.min2(pwr_fl[t] - pwr_dr_forecast, 0) * p_dg)

m.options.IMODE = 3
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()
```

This is the error I get:

```
apm 155.133.14.228_gk_model0 <br><pre> ----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 1.0.1
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------
 
 
 Warning: there is insufficient data in CSV file 155.133.14.228_gk_model0.csv
 @error: Equation Definition
 Equation without an equality (=) or inequality (>,<)
 (185-v80)(185-v81)(185-v82)(185-v83)(185-v84)(185-v85)(185-v86)
 STOPPING...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thank you in advance for your time

Answer (score 1):

Some of the variables in the objective function are an array. Each value needs to either be a single value or else the summation of an array (that also reduces to a single value). Here is a modified version of the problem that solves successfully, but the equations may not be correct:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
import numpy as np

# data for 10th of January
pwr_cl = np.ones(24) * 584  # base load
pwr_fl = [185, 188, 167, 155, 168, 169, 168, 187, 190, 181, 211, 227,
          233, 230, 222, 216, 234, 237, 248, 250, 255, 247, 248, 206]  # variable loads in kW
pwr_dg = [1479.652, 586.589, 1452.378, 1452.822, 1249.333, 1112.853,
          1319.44, 1568.773, 1778.94, 1832.277, 1917.526, 1995.028,
          1955.759, 1900.253, 1781.595, 1548.431, 1495.562, 1496.265,
          1497.333, 1497.333, 1495.562, 1495.041, 1496.586, 1481.391] # renewables production in kW

c_sub = 10  # €/KW
p_grid = [0.1039, 0.09324, 0.08758, 0.07987, 0.09473, 0.1086,
          0.17634, 0.1849, 0.22304, 0.21307, 0.17866, 0.17144,
          0.16287, 0.16202, 0.16835, 0.18127, 0.19067, 0.20084,
          0.19173, 0.18842, 0.1822, 0.17953, 0.17208, 0.143]  # electricity cost from the grid €/kW

m = GEKKO()

# variables I want to optimise
p_sell = m.Array(m.Var, 24, lb=0.2, ub=0.3)  # electricity sale price
p_dg = m.Array(m.Var, 24, lb=0.15, ub=0.25)  # electricity purchase price from renewable sources
pwr_grid = m.Array(m.Var, 24, lb=0, ub=5000)  # power from the grid
pwr_dr_forecast = m.Array(m.Var, 24, lb=-750, ub=750)  # power that can be regulated by batteries


s = m.Intermediate(m.sum(pwr_grid) + m.sum(pwr_dr_forecast))
for t in range(24):
    pwr_grid_val = pwr_cl[t] + pwr_fl[t] - pwr_dg[t]
    m.Equation(s <= pwr_grid_val)
    m.Minimize(p_grid[t] * pwr_grid[t] + pwr_dg[t] * p_dg[t] + c_sub * m.abs3(pwr_dr_forecast[t])
               - m.max3(pwr_fl[t] - pwr_dr_forecast[t], 0) * p_sell[t]
               - m.min3(pwr_fl[t] - pwr_dr_forecast[t], 0) * p_dg[t])

m.options.IMODE = 3
m.options.SOLVER = 1
m.solve()
```

The `m.abs()` function should be replaced by `m.abs2()` or `m.abs3()` for a form that has continuous gradients. It is preferable to use `m.abs3()` and other functions such as `m.min3()` and `m.max3()` because they rely on binary variables for the switch instead of MPCCs that are less reliable.

It is also faster to define the summation once outside of the loop as an intermediate variable `s`.

```py
s = m.Intermediate(m.sum(pwr_grid) + m.sum(pwr_dr_forecast))
```

The solution:

```
 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :            0
   Constants    :            0
   Variables    :          408
   Intermediates:            1
   Connections  :            0
   Equations    :          265
   Residuals    :          264
 
 Number of state variables:            408
 Number of total equations: -          240
 Number of slack variables: -          168
 ---------------------------------------
 Degrees of freedom       :              0
 
 ----------------------------------------------
 Steady State Optimization with APOPT Solver
 ----------------------------------------------
Iter: 1 I: 0 Tm: 0.04 NLPi: 4 Dpth: 0 Lvs: 0 Obj: 1.55E+04 Gap: 0.00E+00
 Successful solution
 
 ---------------------------------------------------
 Solver         :  APOPT (v1.0)
 Solution time  :   5.270000000018626E-002 sec
 Objective      :    15511.4799000000     
 Successful solution
 ---------------------------------------------------
```

Comment: Thank you for the help (and for editing my question so it's more readable)!
You were correct, the code as you wrote it gets to a solution but `m.Equation(s <= pwr_grid_val)` is not what the problem says... I need to have an equality as in equation (2.8): `m.Equation(s == pwr_grid_val))`, which doesn't reach a solution. What can I do to fix this?

Comment: The problem may be infeasible if you don't allow over-production. Maybe use the inequality and minimize `pwr_grid_val`. This will return a feasible solution and minimize any over-production. I'm not sure if the definitions are correct (just guessing based on the names), but the idea to create a feasible solution and minimize any equation deviation can help find a potential solution. Additional grid energy problems are listed here: https://apmonitor.com/do/index.php/Main/EnergyBenchmarks

Comment: I see what you mean regarding over-production. `pwr_grid_val` (is the total demand from the grid and the system energy storage) is a fixed integer value so I can't minimise that, but I tried allowing over-production by setting a negative boundary for power from/to the grid but this doesn't reach a solution anyway. Maybe I'm setting up the problem in an infeasible way...